# "No such file or directory" al añadir la clave publica al archivo authorized_keys2 de la máquina de destino a la que quiero enviar los archivos

Tags: unix, ssh, networking

Siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-copy-a-docker-image-from-one-server-to-another-without-pushing-it-to-a-repository-first), quiero transferar un imagen Docker desde el mio PC Windows10 hasta un otro, Fedora, usando rsync. Por eso necesito  acceso SSH verificado entre las dos máquinas. Por eso siguo [este tutorial](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/hee/cms/emu/fast/FAST-DAQ/ssh_between_2.html) pero tengo problemas al autorizar la clave pública. Pero no soy capaz de hacer esto ingresando a la máquina y luego anexando la clave pública al archivo authorized_keys2

Logro connectarme al Fedora con SSH. Nota al margen: no sé si es sufficiente para transferar un imagen Docker. Me parece que si porque si intento transferarlo desde WSL:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Users/antoi/Documents/Programming/Work/NG$ rsync -avz neo4j.tar ac@192.168.123:Documents/Work
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.123 port 22: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Tal vez es a causa de que lo hizo desde wsl2 mientras que hizo todo el resto desde PowerShell, pero este no tiene rsync.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> rsync -avz neo4j.tar ac@192.168.123:Documents/Work                 rsync : The term 'rsync' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ rsync -avz neo4j.tar ac@192.168.123:Documents/Work
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (rsync:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Entonces si sigo el tutorial para connectarme sin login correctamente también tengo que autorizar la clave pública (en la máquina de destino?) (Step 3.)

Pero mientras que estoy capaz de connectarme con SSH a la maquina de destinacion, no soy capaz transferarlo el public key.

```
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh-keygen -t dsa -f 192.168.1.123
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in 192.168.1.123.
Your public key has been saved in 192.168.1.123.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:necesitoOcultarLosi? antoi@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V
The key's randomart image is:
+---[DSA 1024]----+
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
| necesitoOcultarLosi? |
+----[SHA256]-----+
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> scp 192.168.1.123.pub me@192.168.1.123
        1 file(s) copied.
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection timed out
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.123 port 22: Connection refused
PS C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Work\NG> ssh me@192.168.1.123
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.123 (192.168.1.123)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:S5iZ1NAjwVKK/75sy6TerzplQdCT6bDYI1Fx72h+V1g.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.123' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
me@192.168.1.123's password:
Last login: Wed Dec 22 14:26:46 2021
cat: 192.168.1.123.pub: No such file or directory
[me@fedora ~]$

[me@fedora ~]$ cat 192.168.1.123.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2
cat: 192.168.1.123.pub: No such file or directory
```

¿Qué puedo hacer? En el peor de los casos puedo enviarle un correo electrónico. Pero no sé si esto resolverá mi problema inicial de transferencia de imágenes.

Comment: Con ssh-keygen, crea unarchivo llamado 192.168.1.127.pub, pero copia un archivo llamado 192.168.1.123.pub .  Que pasa?

Comment: Oops Acabo de cambiar @Duston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Su problema es con la sintaxis de scp.  Copyó el archivo 192.168.1.123 a un archivo en el C: llamado me@192.168.1.123.  La sintaxis que quiere es:

```
scp 192.168.1.123 me@192.168.1.123:192.168.1.123.pub
```

El `me@192.168.1.123:` indica el usario y la dirección del servidor.  Desde no tuvo que entrar el clave y no dijo nada del porcentaje indica que no contectó al servidor.

Por ejemplo:

```
c:\Duston>scp 192.168.0.119.pub.pub duston@192.168.0.102:192.168.0.119.pub.pub
duston@192.168.0.102's password:
192.168.0.119.pub.pub                                                                 100%  567   185.1KB/s   00:00

c:\Duston>

duston@duston-laptop:~$ ls 192.168.0.119.pub.pub
192.168.0.119.pub.pub
```